# Problemas ao criar DAO e uma inserção

Tags: c#, crud

Estou começando agora com o C# e estou com uns problemas na hora de desenvolver esse código, eu estava com o objetivo de criar um DAO com uma simples conexão e depois instância-la e logo em seguida fazer a inserção no banco. mas dá um erro que a conexão deve ser aberta, mas eu abro ela lá no DAO, então, dá uma ajuda que estou confuso nisso

**OBS1:** *fiz as mudanças por onde entendi no que o colega **Olivier** sugeriu, porem ainda estou um pouco perdido*

**OBS2:** *Consegui resolver a questão, vou deixar o código, caso alguém esteja começando a estudar o c#*

**DAO.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;



namespace CRUD_MYSQL
{
    public class Dao
    {
        private MySqlConnection conn = null;

        public MySqlConnection conectar()
        {

            string connectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=;database=dbalbuns";

            this.conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

            this.conn.Open();

            try
            {
                if (this.conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Conectado");
                }

                return this.conn;
            }

            catch (Exception)

            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("erro de conexão");

                return this.conn;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**WebForm1.apsx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace CRUD_MYSQL
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Dao conectar = new Dao();

            MySqlConnection Conexao = conectar.conectar();

            string query = "insert into albuns (titulo, descricao, preco) values ('a', 'a', '1')";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, Conexao))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Poste a resposta como resposta, não misture a pergunta com a resposta. Não há problema em responder a própria pergunta. O que fica ruim é a confusão entre os dois posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`connectar()` fecha a conexão `conn.Close();`!

```
string connectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=;database=dbalbuns";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    string query = "insert into albuns (titulo, descricao, preco) values ('a', 'a', '1')";
    //                                muito importante |
    //                                                 V
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn)) {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

O comando `using` fecha a conexão no final "}"

(Eu usei Google para traduzir de/a português. Sorry.)

Comment: May I remove the other (duplicate) user?

Comment: Olá Olivier, fiz as mudanças que você sugeriu, porem ainda estou perdido, principalmente no WebForm1.apsx.cs, na hora que vou instanciar a classe DAO e usar o método conectar onde é necessário abrir a conexão.